# Checking existence of file types via extensions bash

Tags: bash

I need to test if various file types exist in a directory.

I've tried

$    [ -f *.$fileext]

where fileext is the file extension but that does not seem to work.

Both of these methods work

```
function checkext() {
fileext=$1

ls *.$fileext>/dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "We have $fileext files!"
else
  echo "We don't have any $fileext files!"
fi
}
```

and

```
function checkext2() {
extention=$1

filescheck=(`ls *.$1`)
len=${#filescheck[*]}


if [ $len -gt 0 ]
then
 echo "We have $extention files!"
else
 if [ $len -eq 0 ]
 then
   echo "We don't have any $extention files!"
 else
   echo "Error"
 fi
fi
}
```

The second method is less tidy as any ls error is shown so I prefer method 1.

Could people please suggest any improvements, more elegant solutions e.t.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
shopt -s nullglob
[ -z "`echo *.$ext`" ] || echo "YAY WE HAVE FILES"
```

Edit: thanks to @Dennis for pointing out the nullglob

Comment: I like this one nice and neat! Checking string length. Thanks.

Comment: `-bash: [: too many arguments` - Also, if there are no files this will still echo the message unless you `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: @Dennis my mistake on leaving out the quotes ;) and i didn't have a terminal handy to test it; thanks for mentioning the nullglob

Comment: sounds like you might be missing spaces around one of the square brackets '[' Dennis works fine but I will consider your other point thanks.

Comment: it would have worked as is if there was only one file of the extension type in the directory; otherwise it expands to a space-delimited list of the files, each of which is interpreted by test as a separate argument. but I'm pretty sure adding the quotes makes it work fine

Comment: @Tommy: If that were the case, the error would have been `command not found` or `missing ']'`. Michael's comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

filetypes="lyx eps pdf"

for type in $filetypes
do
        files=$(ls *.${type} 2>/dev/null)
        if [ ! -z "$files" ]
        then
                echo "filetype: [$type] exists"
        fi  
done
```